# KendoUI Grid Fetching from Data Source but not Displaying

Tags: json, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

With the code below, I see all the data correctly fetched in the browser console but the gird shows nothing and I get "uncaught error not defined". No idea what that refers to. Can you point me to what needs to be fixed? This is code I lifted off Telerik's site and I changed the datasource type from odata to json and the url to mine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular">
<style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions"></kendo-grid>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    </script>

</div>
</div>

<script>
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "http://localhost:8090/rest/kdxposapi/salesman?app_name=kdxpos",
                beforeSend: function(req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'dolh45p0isg2c8nl9shc3kjee1');
                }
            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
        dataBound: function() {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name",
            width: "120px"
        },{
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            width: "120px"
        }]
    };

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```